# Should I use OLS robust standard errors with FGLS or PSCE?

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

My sample size is 8 banks over 10 years. There is heteroskedasticity but no serial autocorrelation. I use stata 13.